# Efficiently solve Ax = b where A is a 4x4 symmetric metrix and b is 4x1 vector

Tags: c++, opencv, linear-equation

I will solve a small linear system `Ax = b` where `A` is a 4-by-4 **symmetric** matrix stored 16 `double` numbers (actually 10 of them are enough to represent it), `b` is 4-by-1 vector. The problem is, I have to run such kind of systems million times. So I am looking for the most efficient library to solve it. I tried `cv::solve()` method in `OpenCV`, but I still find it slow.

As the matrix `A` is symmetric, I remember `Conjugate Gradient` algorithm may be a good candidate due to its efficiency. However, I have not found a library on it yet(Intel MKL seems have one, but it is designed for sparse matrix, not well-fit for my problem).

Could any one help me with it?

Comment: Is `A` always (or at least several times at a time) the same?

Comment: No, every time I solve it, `A` and `b` will be new.

Comment: If you're looking for a library, this is off-topic, if not, this might be off-topic (and on-topic for [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)).

Comment: Since the dimensions are smalls, and you only have 4 values to guess, I suspect you would be better off hard-coding the solution rather than relying on libraries that may not take all the specifics (like symmetry) into account.

Comment: Did you made experiments with all possible algorithms that solve() can use? Their performance can vary greatly for different sizes of matrix. You can see here all options: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#solve

Answer (score 5):

Since the matrix dimension is fixed, I think you're best off, directly implementing the inverse. 
There exists a ready made formular for this task. You have:

[image: Inverse Matrix formular]

The entries of `B` are given by:
[image: Calculation of the B_ij]

Both formulars are taken from [this site](http://www.cg.info.hiroshima-cu.ac.jp/~miyazaki/knowledge/teche23.html).

You should be able to further simplify the calculation of these entries exploiting the fact, that your matrix is symmetric. If you do that I think you will be faster than any general matrix inverse implementation.

Then you still need to apply `A^-1` to your `b`, which is a simple matrix vector multiplication, you should also hard code, to get best performance.

All this assumes that you really need the best performance for this particular problem. If the matrix dimension changes, or this is not the most critical part of your algorithm, have a look at [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), Lapack/Blas or any other linear algebra library. Solving a dense linear system is the fundamental task, which should be contained in any such library.

Comment: remember to test your code on random matrices against some other solution (e.g. openCV inverse mat solution) to avoid index errors while hardcoding ;)

Comment: This is Cramer's rule. It's probably fine for $3\times3$ matrices but not for $4\times 4$ matrices. LU decomposition is probably faster for this case. LU decomposition is also generally more numerically stable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Solving_linear_equations Students are taught matrix determinants and matrix inverses at an early stage but both can often be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

For God's sake, please don't write your own.
If I understand correctly, you're looking to solve a dense linear system efficiently. This is exactly what LAPACK is for. The version on netlib.org (see [this page](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node38.html) for guidance on which routine you should use) is pretty fast, but if you need something that really screams look at MKL, ATLAS, or perhaps GotoBLAS.

Edit: Since this is a C++ forum, I should add that you can use the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) package to do the solve. It will use some implementation of one of the LAPACK routines.

Comment: The main problem I see, is that LAPACK is not optimized for such tiny systems with 4x4 matrices, but rather for systems with 1000x1000 matrices. Therefore I don't think they get anywhere near a hard coded implementation, in terms of performance. If this is worth the effort implementing it hard coded, depends on how often the calculations will be done. On the other hand, getting started with LAPACK/BLAS is not necessarily easier than a direct implementation.

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the [Eigen main page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), there is a credit to Intel for optimized 4x4 matrix inversion code they included. I'll bet that's plenty fast enough. As @Micka points out, testing is an issue, and you can bet that the Eigen code is plenty well tested.

Comment: Nice, I did not know Eigen (or in this case Intel) has in fact highly optimized code for such small cases. I guess it is usually used for some divide an conquer algorithms where such small problems occur. Your probably right that one won't beat SSE optimized code for that particular problem. For testing I assumed that OP has a working solver to test against, and only wants a high performance variant. Otherwise Eigen is surely a good candidate to test against.

Answer (score 1):

The topic is probably out of date, hovewer i solve very similiar problem and this topic could be useful for others.

4 dimensions are quite small, thus algorithms for direct computation of matrix inversion are efficient. Hovewer, if you need A-matrix for one solution only, there is no need to calculate a whole inversion. One can see that dividing by determinant (an operation in matrix inversion) is not nessesary for all terms of inverse matrix. You can divide only 4 terms of solution instead of all 16 matrix terms. There is also some another optimization. Here is my implementation of 4D-solver (c++ code)

```
void getsub(double* sub, double* mat, double* vec)
{
*(sub++) = *(mat  ) * *(mat+5) - *(mat+1) * *(mat+4);
*(sub++) = *(mat  ) * *(mat+6) - *(mat+2) * *(mat+4);
*(sub++) = *(mat  ) * *(mat+7) - *(mat+3) * *(mat+4);
*(sub++) = *(mat  ) * *(vec+1) - *(vec  ) * *(mat+4);
*(sub++) = *(mat+1) * *(mat+6) - *(mat+2) * *(mat+5);
*(sub++) = *(mat+1) * *(mat+7) - *(mat+3) * *(mat+5);
*(sub++) = *(mat+1) * *(vec+1) - *(vec  ) * *(mat+5);
*(sub++) = *(mat+2) * *(mat+7) - *(mat+3) * *(mat+6);
*(sub++) = *(mat+2) * *(vec+1) - *(vec  ) * *(mat+6);
*(sub  ) = *(mat+3) * *(vec+1) - *(vec  ) * *(mat+7);
}

void solver_4D(double* mat, double* vec)
{
    double a[10], b[10]; // values of 20 specific 2D subdeterminants

    getsub(&a[0], mat, vec);
    getsub(&b[0], mat+8, vec+2);

    *(vec++) = a[5]*b[8] + a[8]*b[5] - a[6]*b[7] - a[7]*b[6] - a[4]*b[9] - a[9]*b[4];
    *(vec++) = a[1]*b[9] + a[9]*b[1] + a[3]*b[7] + a[7]*b[3] - a[2]*b[8] - a[8]*b[2];
    *(vec++) = a[2]*b[6] + a[6]*b[2] - a[0]*b[9] - a[9]*b[0] - a[3]*b[5] - a[5]*b[3];
    *(vec  ) = a[0]*b[8] + a[8]*b[0] + a[3]*b[4] + a[4]*b[3] - a[6]*b[1] - a[1]*b[6];

    register double idet = 1./(a[0]*b[7] + a[7]*b[0] + a[2]*b[4] + a[4]*b[2] - a[5]*b[1] - a[1]*b[5]);

    *(vec--) *= idet;
    *(vec--) *= idet;
    *(vec--) *= idet;
    *(vec  ) *= idet;
}
```

`*mat` represent pointer into A-matrix in form

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

and `*vec` represent inertial vector in form `0 1 2 3`. Method throw away inertial vector and replace them by the new one.

You need 74 multiplications and one divide only. This method is probably suitable for SSE coders (most of operations are dual) if you are experienced in SSE optimization.

This one works well for all invertible A-matrix in general. You can use identity `a[7] = b[0]` for symmetric A-matrix. It's not much, but the orignal code for general 4-dimensional invertible A-matrix is still pretty fast.